# 10G Network Card stopped working with latest kernel update (5.13.0-40)

Tags: networking, drivers, kernel, broadcom

So I went from 5.13.0-39 to 5.13.0-40 - shouldn't be a big deal, very minor rev right?  (Running KUbuntu 21.10)

Finishes the upgrade with zero errors, reboots.  No network.   bond0 connection is still there (and showing up for some reason) but the underlying Broadcom BCM57810 card underneath (dual-port CNA) isn't working, doesn't even show up in ifconfig -a.

Tried booting back to 5.13.0-39 and it worked again, so it wasn't the card (I've seen cards fail on reboots before)

lshw -C network - shows both cards present but "UNCLAIMED" and I have to think that the drivers were, for some stupid reason, pulled out of the hardware enablement.

Anyone else seen this and know a fix?  I hate using vendor-provided drivers because I don't feel like they're as tested against the small incremental kernel updates, etc, but who knows, maybe it's the better option in this case.

Edit: Per Requested -

```
# dkms status
nvidia, 510.60.02, 5.13.0-39-generic, x86_64: installed

# lshw -C network
  *-network:0 UNCLAIMED
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: NetXtreme II BCM57810 10 Gigabit Ethernet
       vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:6c:00.0
       version: 10
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm vpd msi msix pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: iomemory:400-3ff iomemory:400-3ff iomemory:400-3ff memory:404c000000-404c7fffff memory:404b800000-404bffffff memory:404c810000-404c81ffff memory:6e480000-6e4fffff
  *-network:1 UNCLAIMED
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: NetXtreme II BCM57810 10 Gigabit Ethernet
       vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
       physical id: 0.1
       bus info: pci@0000:6c:00.1
       version: 10
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm vpd msi msix pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: iomemory:400-3ff iomemory:400-3ff iomemory:400-3ff memory:404b000000-404b7fffff memory:404a800000-404affffff memory:404c800000-404c80ffff memory:6e400000-6e47ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: bond0
       serial: <redacted>
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=bonding driverversion=5.13.0-40-generic firmware=2 ip=<redacted> link=no master=yes multicast=yes

# cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager

# dpkg -s linux-modules-extra-5.13.0-40-generic | grep Status
Status: install ok installed
```

Comment: Edit your question and show me `dkms status` and `sudo lshw -C network` and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `sudo dpkg -s linux-modules-extra-5.13.0-40-generic | grep Status` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @heynnema -done, thanks.  I had to go around about because I'd already uninstalled the -40 update.

Comment: @chili555 - Done - see above.

Comment: See the accepted answer at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/671573/broadcom-netxtreme-ii-bcm57810-10-gigabit-ethernet-appearing-as-unclaimed-on-ubu

Comment: @chili555 - Unfortunately, that didn't seem to fix it.  I'm about ready to do a clean install, I can't be without my desktop for this kind of time.  (Currently working on 5.13.0-39, so I'm staying there for the time being.)